# GUI tool for branching GIT

Tags: windows, git

I am taking over some stuff which developers have had in Git for several years.
It would be nice to see all branches that were made and relation ships much the same as you can do in any source control tool that has a GUI.
I tried  Sourcetree and the Visual Studio Plug for GIT, which are both so slow,  it drives you back to the command line.
Is there a GUI tool for more than check in and out?

Comment: VS has native support for Git. You don't need any plugin. Are you using an old version of VS? Most people use TortoiseGit through Windows Explorer itself though. Best option is to install it using chocolatey, as this will automatically install all dependencies

Comment: What you are lookin for is the Revision graph. Also check [this question on how to pretty print the revision graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs) - there are an insane number of different tools

Comment: Ya,  I was looking for more of a GUI and not 30 pages of command output.

Comment: I suspect you didn't check all the tools, just checked the first response. There are a *lot* of tools for pretty printing. For daily use though, the revision graph in TortoiseGit isn't bad. In any case, pretty printing the entire history is definitely slower than a daily check of the revision graph. In your case, you need to create the graph just once and study it

Comment: I'm flagging this question as off-topic, since it's basically asking for external software (basically an external resource) that's not necessarily directly involved in the development process. You may recieve better answers over at [softwarerecs.se], but please read their [help center](http://softwarerecommendations.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Git Gui tool from the https://git-scm.com/download/win
This tool is very fast, useful and very simple

Comment: How long have they had this?

Comment: Nevermind, this is just the Git download.

Comment: Sorry, I'am not sure that I understand you correctly. You mean when they made the first release ?